# Servce Fabric Reverse Proxy Integration in ASP.NET Core 404 Response

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm working on an implementation of `ICommunicationClient` and accompanying stuff for HTTP protocol communication which should be compatible with SF reverse proxy. The most subtle part for me is retry policy. According to Azure docs for 404 errors reverse proxy relies on X-Service-Fabric header to be returned from web service when deciding if it should retry.

ASP.NET Core provides [middleware](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore/ServiceFabricReverseProxyIntegrationMiddleware.cs) for integration with a reverse proxy which adds X-Service-Fabric header to every 404 response.

Assume we have the scenario when `ServicePartitionClient` cached the endpoint for a stateless service listening on port 3001. At some point, this service may be moved to another node. On the first node, the Service Fabric runtime allocates a different service with its own endpoints but using the same middleware and listening on the same 3001 port.

When a client tries to call the original service at its old (cached) address it will receive 404 response containing the `X-Service-Fabric` header. According to reverse proxy policies it shouldn't retry, but for me, it seems like the client will stay connected to the wrong service forever and won't attempt to re-resolve the endpoint.

I can't find any information about this case in the documentation, did I miss something here? Is it safe to rely on this standard middleware and don't do retry attempts on 404 errors with X-Service-Fabric: ResourceNotFound header?

Comment: Are you possibly conflating the 404 that _your_ application issues with the 404 issued by whatever service assumed residency in your migrated node? I would assume you have no control over a node your application is no longer running in

Comment: @JoshE: I have no control over how service fabric manages service lifecycle, failovers, port assignments etc. Services can be randomly moved around nodes and there is probability that eventually different SF service will start listening the address previously used by other service

Comment: right, and it's the SF's responsibility to ensure correct routing of requests through the fabric. It's a client's responsibility to invalidate its own cache, for instance, when it receives a 404 from a cached endpoint. You can't control node migration but (if you're the client) you can control what you do in response to it

Comment: @JoshE: exactly, client provides retry mechanism based on error responses, reverse proxy behavior is to retry 404 and resolve new endpoint  only when response doesn't contain "X-Service-Fabric: ResourceNotFound" header, but in scenario I described it looks like it's possible that client will receive this header from another fabric service and will think that it stays connected to the correct provider, for me it looks like the only safe option is to retry every 404 response which is what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the described case the communication client will be invalidated by staying connected to the wrong service. It is [recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#a-case-of-mistaken-identity) to use unique URL prefixes for services with dynamically-assigned port to handle those scenarios.

In ASP.NET Core programmers can leverage [`ServiceFabricMiddleware`](https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore/ServiceFabricMiddleware.cs) which checks URL prefixes and returns 410 Gone if they don't match. Then HTTP implementation of `ICommunicationClient` can retry with re-resolving endpoint only for 410 responses and don't perform any retries on 404 response with `X-Service-Fabric: ResourceNotFound` header if reverse proxy integration is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your given scenario, when your Client encounters a 404, the `X-Service-Fabric:ResourceNotFound` header isn't the only attribute your code could examine when deciding whether or not to retry some operation.

To simplistically address your concern that your client won't be able to tell the difference between a "friendly" node and a "newly arrived" node, and since you're already working with http headers, you could add a custom HTTP header to outgoing responses to identify that a request comes from your application.
When the client receives a 404, you can simply check for the presence of your custom header to answer the question of whether or not it's a "legit" retry. Of course, adding a custom HTTP header just for the sake of this validation check may be more of a global solution to a local problem. *Ed: goes without saying that this should not be used to make security decisions by the application*

A more elegant and complex means of accomplishing the same would be to deduce the same result using a different combination of HTTP headers and response attributes (e.g., see if some other headers are expected/unexpected), but this could also be a hyper-local solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer, straightforward solution I was thinking about is to create filter that will add custom header after request was processed by controller, this will indicate that 404 is not related to invalid address and request hit correct endpoint and was processed by correct service, but main concerns in my question are why ASP.NET Core does this on middleware level instead of providing action filter and does it mean that SF reverse proxy behavior will be incorrect in such scenarios

Comment: I would reason that the reason is because allowing awareness of an underlying infrastructure concern in layers higher up in the stack could bring, allow, or encourage undesired coupling and mixing of concerns. You might consider setting your header in middleware as well to shield your application logic from it and concerns like retry